# Database schema for activity related to many entities

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema, crm

How to build a nice schema for activities in a database? 
One activity can relate to one of 50 different entities.

For now i see only 3 solutions:

1. Table "activity" contains 50 columns with foreignkeys to the other entities.

   *This results in a very big table, which i do not like.*
2. Each entity has its own "activity"-Table.

   *This solution results in nearly doubling the tables in my database, but its clearer. Still not the best solution.*
3. Dirty one: "activity"-table contains one "entityType"-column with the entity-table-name and a other "entityId"-columns with the id to the entity.

   *But this solution break all foreign-keys and allows to store crap data in my activity table.*

Perhaps somebody of you build a CRM and had to face with the same problem.
Does anyone have a better and clean solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like i see, there is only a decission to make. First and second possibility are good because the keep the consistency of the db. In my case i decided to use 1. possibility.